# laravel eloquent relation problems belongsToMany 3 Models in pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, eager-loading

I have a case with several models. Order Model, Product Model, Port Model, and Logistic Model.
With an `Order belongsTo Many Products`, `Order Belongs To Port with 'to_port_id'` ,`Order Belongs To Logistic with 'logistic_id'`, `Product belongs To Port with 'from_port_id'`,

`from_port_id , to_port_id ,logistic_id and unit_price` combined with a pivot table .

And now I want to ask. How to retrieve an order with different products with corresponding `from_port_id,to_port_id,logistic_id` to get different unit_price with the eager load as little sql as possible?

**Order Model**

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| to_port_id   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logistic_id  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Product Model**

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| from_port_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**LogisticPort  PivotModel**

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| from_port_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| to_port_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| logistic_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| unit_price   | decimal(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

----------update -------------------------

```
    class Product extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'product';





        /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    public function orderTransact(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\OrderTransact','order_transact_product','product_id','order_transact_id')->withPivot(['unique_order_product_id','order_quantity_in_log','order_product_status_id ','confirmed_delivery_date','expected_ETD','due_at','downpayment','deposit','total','feedback','created_at','updated_at','tracking_no','weight','logistic_cost'])->using('App\Models\OrderTransactProduct')->as('order_product');
    }


    public function orderProduct(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderTransactProduct','product_id','id');
    }


    public function fromLogisticPort(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\LogisticPort','from_port_id','id');
    }




}

    class LogisticPort extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'logistic_port';
    


    public function logisticFrom(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Logistic','logistic_port_logistic','from_port_id','logistic_id')->withPivot(['to_port_id','courier_charges_unit'])->using('App\Models\LogisticPortLogistic');
    }
    public function logisticTo()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Logistic','logistic_port_logistic','to_port_id','logistic_id')->withPivot(['from_port_id','courier_charges_unit'])->using('App\Models\LogisticPortLogistic');
    }

    public function logisticPortFrom(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\LogisticPort','logistic_port_logistic','to_port_id','from_port_id')->withPivot(['logistic_id','courier_charges_unit'])->using('App\Models\LogisticPortLogistic');
    }
    public function logisticPortTo(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\LogisticPort','logistic_port_logistic','from_port_id','to_port_id')->withPivot(['logistic_id','courier_charges_unit'])->using('App\Models\LogisticPortLogistic');
    }


    public function toPivotLogisticPort(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LogisticPortLogistic','to_port_id','id');
    }

    public function product(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product','from_port_id','id');
    }

    public function orderTransact(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderTransact','from_port_id','id');
    }


}



    class Logistic extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'logistic';


    public function orderTransact(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderTransact','order_transact_id','id');
    }
    public function logisticPortFrom(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\LogisticPort','logistic_port_logistic','logistic_id','from_port_id')->withPivot(['to_port_id','courier_charges_unit'])->using('App\Models\LogisticPortLogistic');

    }
    public function logisticPortTo(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\LogisticPort','logistic_port_logistic','logistic_id','to_port_id')->withPivot(['from_port_id','courier_charges_unit'])->using('App\Models\LogisticPortLogistic');
    }

}



    class OrderTransact extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'order_transact';

            /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    public function logistic(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Logistic','logistic_id','id');
    }



    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product','order_transact_product','order_transact_id','product_id')->withPivot(['unique_order_product_id','order_quantity_in_log','order_product_status_id','confirmed_delivery_date','expected_ETD','due_at','downpayment','deposit','total','feedback','created_at','updated_at','tracking_no','weight','logistic_cost'])->using('App\Models\OrderTransactProduct')->as('order_product');
    }

    public function orderProduct(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderTransactProduct','order_transact_id','id');
    }

    public function toLogisticPort(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\LogisticPort','to_port_id','id');
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to do

Comment: please update your  all realtionship models here

Comment: i dont know what the relationship names that you are used in your project so its hard to write  code for you .. so please update the models also

Comment: I think you should apply morphological relationship for your case instead of many to many with 3 tables. In fact, morphological relationship is introduced for this scenario where more than 2 models can be related to each other.

Comment: would you introduce in more details?thanks